# Push fragment into Linear or Relative Layout instead of frame layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Is there any advantage or disadvantage to push fragments into layouts other than Frame layout ? And do you recommend any of it ?

I tried pushing fragment into Relative Layout and I saw that my fragment stays left-top of the screen but if i push it into Frame It works well. (Both height and width are match_parent in the inflated layout)

Comment: i think it will be not a good practice to add fragment in liner layout,relative layout because thats layout are not good for fragment alignment,gravity will disturb  fragment you should use frame layout for fragments that is good practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fragment can be generally added to any [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) according to the [guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding). But on the other hand the [`FrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)'s documentation states that "Child views are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top" which I guess is an advantage over the other ViewGroups for the fragment backstack

Comment: I accept your answer but I am using replace so It shouldn't be a problem. I was just curious If there is any advantage using other view groups I guess there isn't